# How can I use a list from another class to show one List on two Screens?

Tags: list, class, flutter, dart, clone

I have created a non-static list. With buttons, you can add and delete elements to this list. Now I want to display this list on two screens. On one screen I want to use a ListView, on the other screen a StackCard.builder. My target is that there is only one list at a time - if it is changed in one Screen, it should change identically automatically in the other Screen.

Now to my question: How can I use the list I created in one class in the other class?

I would be very happy about an answer, thanks in advance for all who look at my problem!

[Here is the Code for the Screen with the List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqUQR.png)

[Here is the second screen, where I try to show the List with the StackCard.builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXwRA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using provider is good option, you can **notifylisteners** from the class where you have functions for adding etc.. and notify after every function. At the end you can show your list via **Consumer**. For more info you can check [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider/example).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried it and now I have a List, which I can share, but all my Functions don´t work anymore... But may it could be also that the functions work and only the screen doesn't update - it would be really great if you can help me ones more - Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64151163/flutter-my-screen-doesnt-update-when-i-update-my-list-in-the-provider-trough-f

Comment: You can check wheter it works or not in debug mode however if function works your value supposed to update because you do it with provider. I ll check your post :)